# Muscular body building by gym

Tags: bodybuilding, gym

Is joining a gym for getting a muscular body and good physique really worth it?

I mean, how beneficial is a gym membership for staying in shape?

Comment: Can you make the question a bit clearer? At least I don't understand if others can do.

Comment: Clear language barrier. Please try using google translate or asking someone to help you formulate your question properly. If youre asking if "going to the gym is worth it, my goal is gaining weight and toned physique" then the answer is "yes it is. you will have to do some form of resistance training and weight training is a good one"

Comment: I've flagged this as it is a very subjective question. Noone can answer if joining a gym is *worth it*, its an option, but no less valid that others.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get a muscular physique in your home gym than you might encounter several problems. The most  common being:

1. Motivation
2. Lack of form while performing the exercises (usually corrected by a trainer)
3. No training program (some can be gotten by the internet, but usually it's best to get one custom made for you)
4. Equipement

---

Personally, I've done both and I can really say that going to the gym is the way to go. You pay for your membership but you also get what you're paying for. You have all the training equipement you need, trainers and training programs.

You even make friends, you can set goals by seeing what others are lifting. Seeing others in the same state as you're in is also motivating.

Although, if you're trying to get fit and have nice endurance. Training outside can be very beneficial also. That being said, there are still many benefits to training endurance in a gym as well.

All in all, yes it is worth going to the gym. The equipment, people, training programs and trainers make it worth your while.